# POST array through PHP and get in Python

Tags: php, python

I am posting a array

```
$name[0] = "anurag";
$name[1] = "abhishek"; 
$ch = curl_init('http://localhost:8000/v0/url-generator');
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "name=$name");
curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

In python I got name = array .

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST["name"]

print name
```

output = array.

I would like to output this in python:

```
name = ['anurag','abhishek']
```

Comment: what you are trying to do REST request ?

Answer (score 1):

Implode $name in your PHP so that you send a string to the curl request instead of an array

http://PHP.net/implode

And then split the value in python. Or use json arrays

Answer (score 0):

First use `json_encode($name)`
send this value to the python program

If you are sending the REST body so in python side you can try like

```
try:
    body = self.request.body
    body_loads = loads(body)
except Exception as e:
    LOG_WARNING('Exception: %s', str(e))
    return WebReturn(self,httplib.FORBIDDEN, {'reason':'Body is not Define '},{'data':"Msg"})
    get = None
get = dict2obj(body_loads)
```

Here is dict2obj

```
def dict2obj(d):
        if isinstance(d, list):
            d = [dict2obj(x) for x in d]
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            return d
        class C(object):
            pass
        o = C()
        for k in d:
            o.__dict__[k] = dict2obj(d[k])
        return o
```

Hpe this will help you